# Indexed Families of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $B_n=(0,1/n]$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
>
> $\qquad$(a) For each $n\in\Bbb N$, find $\bigcap_{k=1}^nB_k$ and $\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k$.
> $\qquad$(b) Find $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$.

My attempt:

a.)

1. The intersection for any $n$ would be $(0, 1/n)$.  $(0, 1/n)$ for the largest $n$ would be the largest intersection because it would be the smallest range of numbers in $(0, 1/1]$.
2. The union for any $n$ would be $(0, 1]$. Because the first would be $(0, 1/1]$ and that unioned with anything else within $(0, 1]$ is $(0, 1]$.

b.)

1. The intersection is empty. As $n$ nears infinity, $1/n$ approaches $0$. There is no overlap between $(0, 0]$ and any other set $(0, 1/n]$.
2. The biggest set as $n$ approaches infinity is when $n = 1$. With $n = 1$, we get $(0, 1]$. Every other range will be $(0, 1/n]$ which is contained in $(0, 1]$. So the union is $(0, 1]$.

Comment: Try to [type up your question nicely](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Fr (a), you can check your answer for small $n$ values. If $n=2$, the intersection is $(0,1/1]\cap(0,1/2])$. This is $(0,1/2]$, but your answer is $(0,1/2)$, which is different. ($1/2$ is in the intersection, but not your answer.) Be careful with phrases like “the largest intersection.” What does it mean? For (b)(1), try using the definition of intersection. A number is in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ if it is in each of the sets $B_n$. Finally, looking at the “smallest” or “largest” set may be useful only if the sets are nested. They are here, but mention that if your claims depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

a.) The intersection $\bigcap_{k=1}^nB_K$ is equal to $(0,\frac1n]$, as @SteveKass pointed out in comments. It's not hard to show that for any sets $x,y$, if $y$ is a proper subset of $x$, then $x\cap y=y$, and this logic extends to more arguments of the intersection operator. Since for each $i<j\leq n$, $B_j$ is a sub-interval of $B_i$, we get the whole intersection. For #2, from similar logic based on "$y$ subset of $x$ implies $x\cup y=x$", we get that $\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_k=(0,1]$.

b.) A real number is in $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ iff it's in every $B_n$, and in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ iff it's in at least one of the $B_n$. So right away we get the answer to #2, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n=(0,1]$. For #1 note that for every real $x$ in the interval $(0,1]$ there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x>1/n$ and therefore $x\notin(0,\frac1n]$. Since this applies to all reals in $(0,1]$, we end up excluding all those reals from the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, so the intersection is empty.